# JavaScript: Replace hexadecimal character

Tags: javascript, url

I have a string such as `"%2Fu%2F2069290%2F"` in JavaScript (extracted from a web page). How do I get the human-readable version of that string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short version**: Use `decodeURIComponent()`.

**Longer version**: In older versions of JavaScript you could use `unescape()` but that has been deprecated since it only works properly for the LATIN1/ISO8859-1 codeset, so you really want to use `decodeURIComponent()` which is supported by all modern browsers.

```
 var c = decodeURIComponent("%2Fu%2F2069290%2F"));
```

Comment: +1 For the additional information about `unescape` and `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: unescape/escape are DOM functions (but not part of any spec) that are supported by some browsers to varying degrees (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.unescape). At least in TraceMonkey, escaping/unescaping non-latin1 codes works fine.

decodeURIComponent/encodeURIComponent are core javascript functions supported by all javascript engines, including the engines in browsers (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp). 

So best to stick with Johan and Darin's answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(decodeURIComponent("%2Fu%2F2069290%2F"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unescape()` function, eg:

```
alert(unescape("%2Fu%2F2069290%2F"));
```

Answer (score 0):

with unescape() ?